# Beta particle range

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

I was working on an experiment using the Geiger counter to determine the range of beta particles through different materials. The range is to be determined experimentally and compared to the theoretical prediction. What I cant quite figure out is how do I account for the particles absorbed in air and the entrance of the counter itself. For example if the particles moved through 1mm of cardboard, then 10cm of air and finally through the 'window' of the GM counter before reaching the counter and say the counter reads 1200 particles /2 mins, how do I adjust the reading of the counter to account for the absorption by air and the window of the counter (40g/cm^2 mass per unit area given).

Comment: Get counts without anything between the source and the counter...

Comment: You are not being asked to perform absolute calorimetry, i.e. to measure the total energy flux of the source. That is, as you noticed. indeed a hard problem (but it can be done, e.g. with an ionization chamber that the sample is placed inside of). All you have to do is to measure how much additional loss the insertion of a piece of cardboard etc. causes.